# looping through element of XDocument and getting specific attributes

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am currently in the process of rewriting my XmlDocument and XmlElements to XDocument and XElement. I've run into a small problem, I used to simply select a single node `ModuleRequests` and than loop through it. I thought simple right I'll just rewrite this:

```
var propertiesRequested = new XmlDocument();
propertiesRequested.LoadXml(propertiesConfiguration);
var requests = propertiesRequested.SelectSingleNode("ModuleRequests");
foreach (XmlNode request in requests)
{
    var propertyValue = request.Attributes["Id"].Value;

    if (systemProperties.ContainsKey(propertyValue) == false)
    {
        systemProperties.Add(propertyValue, request.Attributes["Request"].Value);
    }
}
```

To this:

```
var propertiesRequested = XDocument.Parse(propertiesConfiguration);
var requests = propertiesRequested.Element("ModuleRequests");

foreach (XNode request in requests)
{
    var propertyValue = request.Attributes["Id"].Value;

    if (systemProperties.ContainsKey(propertyValue) == false)
    {
        systemProperties.Add(propertyValue, request.Attributes["Request"].Value);
    }
}
```

Well needless to say it isn't that easy, then I thought fine i'll make it:

```
foreach(XNode request in requests.Nodes())
```

but this gave me even more problems since an XNode does not have an attribute.

As you can probably tell I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to xml reading. I'm hoping someone can help me out. What is the correct way to rewrite from XmlDocument to XDocument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`XElement.Elements()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342765%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to iterate through all child elements of your `requests` element, then use [`XElement.Attribute(XName name)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.attribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to fetch the specified attribute by name.

You *might* also consider [explicitly casting your `XAttribute` to a string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339184(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than using the [`Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xattribute.value(v=vs.110).aspx) property, as the former will return `null` on a missing attribute rather than generating a null reference exception.

Thus:

```
var propertiesRequested = XDocument.Parse(propertiesConfiguration);
var requests = propertiesRequested.Element("ModuleRequests");
foreach (var request in requests.Elements())
{
    var propertyValue = (string)request.Attribute("Id");

    if (systemProperties.ContainsKey(propertyValue) == false)
    {
        systemProperties.Add(propertyValue, (string)request.Attribute("Request"));
    }
}
```